# Chartjs [React] - Radar Chart - Spacing Bottom

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Why does the `Radar` chart in `react-chartjs-2` adds so much padding/spacing to the bottom of the chart? Is there a way to remove this?
[image]

Example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-radar-botttom-spacing-13bmst